# Compiled Linux-Kernel, crach, 40GB disk full, temp folder?

Tags: linux, kernel, compile

As i was compilenig a Linux-Kernel on [KDE neon GNU/Linux](https://bitbucket.org/jeromerobert/k4dirstat/wiki/Home) (upgrade to ubuntu 18.04/Linux-Kernel 4.20.5) the computer crashed and now my Linux pratition (40GB) is full.
Where is the directory where the **gcc compiler** stores files while its compiling?
I already cleand the partition with [BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org/) but still 30GB data on the disk, it sould be around 9GB.

With a greeting

---

Thanks for the quick response.
I fetched the [k4dirstat](https://bitbucket.org/jeromerobert/k4dirstat/wiki/Home) an tryd to install...

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-

```
3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Gettext (missing: GETTEXT_MSGMERGE_EXECUTABLE
  GETTEXT_MSGFMT_EXECUTABLE)
```

README:

> ## Overview
>
> See the
>   [wiki](https://bitbucket.org/jeromerobert/k4dirstat/wiki/Home).
>
> ## Building
>
> First install [Qt 5](http://www.qt.io) and [KDE Framework
>   5](https://www.kde.org) headers. On Debian and its derivatives it can
>   be done with:
>
> ````
> libkf5coreaddons-dev \  libkf5i18n-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev
> libkf5doctools-dev libkf5kio-dev ```
>
> Then run [cmake](http://www.cmake.org):
>
>     cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/where/to/install
>     make install
> ````

Comment: You can easily find out what’s occupying space using `ncdu` or a similar tool. Since you have KDE, perhaps `KDirStat`.

Comment: OK, i got it.Its the: /usr/src/linux-4.20.5 directory, got 16.xxGB date in it.

Comment: If you have another suitable drive/partition elsewhere, you can do all your building there and just transfer the finished result to your root partition. It might take a few tweaks to tell the build apparatus to use another location, but it will prevent you from running out of space on your root partition.

Comment: fixed with the command: make clean

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution would be to look for large directories and files.

```
du -hc / | sort -rh | less
```

will list disk usage of your root partition in human readable format with totals and then sort it into descending order putting the output into a pager so you can see it instead of having it all fly by. All the big stuff will be displayed first.

If there are a lot of restricted directories, this can be run with `sudo` so it can see into them as well.

If you need to run it on all of root or another large partition/file tree, it may take awhile to complete. The `sort` can't put anything out until it has all the input from `du`.

If you get a lot of error messages about not being able to examine restricted directories as a regular user, you can use

```
du -hc / 2>/dev/null | sort -rh | less
```

to suppress the error messages.

Comment: THX, i fixed it with the command: make clean